# Full stack web app with Angular 6 working only in Chrome

Tags: python, django, angular, postgresql

I am trying to build a full stack web app for data visualization using Angular 6, Django 2.1, Python 3.5 and Postgresql. Here is the code:
https://github.com/shivkiyer/dataviz

I have deployed the app on my VPS:
http://webdevandresearch.com/dataviz/

This app works only in Google Chrome and not in Firefox or Internet Explorer. Specifically, it does not load the dataset when I click the button. I thought it must be something about the way I have added the click listener, but other aspects are working such as clicking on buttons to navigate or show/hide details. So it is not as if click listeners on buttons are not at all working.

This is the error message:

```
TypeError: _co.errorMessage is undefined
Stack trace:
View_DataAnalyticsComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/DataAnalyticsComponent.ngfactory.js:140:9
debugUpdateDirectives@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:44159:12
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43556:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43797:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43739:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43562:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43797:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43760:17
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43557:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43797:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43739:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:43562:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:44449:22
debugCheckAndUpdateView@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:44127:12
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:41943:13
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:37676:58
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:37676:13
next/<@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:37567:99
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2726:17
onInvoke@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36925:24
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2725:37
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2485:24
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36839:16
next@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:37567:69
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36656:36
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:69153:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:69091:17
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:69035:9
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:69012:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:68778:17
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36640:54
checkStable@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36894:13
onLeave@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36961:5
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:3030/vendor.js:36919:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2757:41
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2530:28
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:2833:24
invokeTask@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:4079:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:3030/polyfills.js:4105:17
```

This error is from my dev server on my local computer. The Angular dev server does not throw any errors. On my Django server I am seeing a 301 to the GET requests being sent from the Angular dev server in Firefox. On my Google Chrome, the GET requests are 200 status. So, the HTTP requests sent my the Angular dev server are messed up in Firefox. On my Google Chrome this works perfectly fine.

Comment: I try the link on firefox and works ok. I login as guest and click on something and list some rows

Comment: So you are able to view the data set? You need to click on Load button after choosing a data set from the drop down. Which version of Firefox are you using? Mine is 60.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already enabled your polyfills? in FireFox your GET request to /api/load-file/1 is returning an HTTP 301. but chrome sucessfully reads the json via the polyfill.

Comment: This is my polyfills.ts file https://github.com/shivkiyer/dataviz/blob/master/sample_pandas_app/frontend/src/polyfills.ts. I guess all the lines related to Edge an Explorer will have to be enabled. Is there anything specific for Firefox?